# Sharing model between documents in a document-based app

Tags: ios, macos, core-data

My app is a document-based and uses `NSPersistentDocument` to manage its Core Data stack.

It works great when each document has its own data, but now I want **documents to share parts of their model**.
In my case, the users import large files and I don't want to copy them for each document.

**I want to have a model that is tight to the app itself and not to the particular document.**

I'm not really sure how to go about it. `NSPersistentDocument` provides some methods to override for configuring Core Data stack but I don't know how to set it up.
Can anyone give me some tips how to achieve that?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you could implement some sort of data manager you then access via delegation. This way, the original data stays in one place and all the individual documents have access to it. When opening documents, have the system check what has already been loaded into the manager and what hasn't.

Answer (score 0):

very interesting case ,

NSPersistentDocument : A document object that can integrate with Core Data
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspersistentdocument#relationships

### I would add my 2 pennies for MVC ideology:

> The Model-View-Controller (MVC) is an architectural pattern that separates an application into three main logical components: the model, the view, and the controller. Each of these components are built to handle specific development aspects of an application.

while its great for relational databases like SQL where cascade delete is possible, and other query based operations.

but the moment you want to couple data between 2 objects you will run into few issues.

- if any of the document/record depends on other siblings, you need to sync them, which is usually a pain in a**.
- if any document is very big, your DB will start sweating already, if it has cascade dependencies to other members of db.

### Possible solutions

since the persistent document can integrate with the core data, try putting any new data to core data and calculate difference from there.

### ideology behind design principles

```
Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
```

[here is the full pdf](https://docplayer.net/5046271-Nspersistentdocument-core-data-tutorial-for-mac-os-x-v10-4-retired-document.html)

Comment: I actually ended up implementing this by having multiple stores. More details in my another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64808268/multiple-persistent-store-coordinators-opening-the-same-store-dont-see-each

Comment: do whatever you like, but keep these 3 principles in mind. `Beautiful is better than ugly.`
`Explicit is better than implicit.`
`Simple is better than complex.`

Comment: Thanks man :) I do however think that my solution is quite elegant. It seems to me that Core Data was built with those scenarios in mind - thus the support for having multiple stores. I wasn't sure how to solve the "sync" part but then I figured out it's just a matter of responding to the "save" notification and merging appropriate changes - which is just a few lines of code. :)